# Best way to develop WordPress site filled with pages like this

Tags: wordpress

I got designs for pages that all look pretty much like this:

[page mixed with editable text/photos and custom post types loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQdTK.jpg)

What is the best way to develop theme like this? Let's say client ic complete noob when it comes to HTML/CSS (and even WordPress, which he demands)

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are searching for? Tips or step by step what I would do?

Comment: Ok, so every page should be a mix of content that should be editable through wordpress page editor, AND some dynamic content, like list of jobs (custom post type). My problem is, after that list of jobs, there is another part of page that should be editable. 

Basically, it's a mix of <?php the_content(); ?>, then some wp_loop, then again <?php the_content(); ?> .... and almost every page is like that

Comment: I mean, it is doable, and I've done it. It just seems there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to develop themes like this is using Bootstrap + WP Theme Development together.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: what about using Visual Composer? (it has built in frontend editor)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fragments like jobs or article list within the content you can add this functionality by shortcodes - https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API. Let me know if you need example ( like post or job listing with shortcode ) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I though of it aswell. Problem is, the example I posted is oversimplified. It's way more complicated on real website.

Comment: You can use custom fields to modify the content as well. Good custom field plugins are : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ and https://carbonfields.net/docs/

Answer (score 0):

If you can do some custom page template development for the Wordpress Theme I would highly recommend using [Advanced Custom Fields Pro](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) to handle the content entry. It costs $$ but is well worth it. I use this plugin for most of my Wordpress development.

Specifically, I would recommend the [ACF Flexible Content field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) to make the kind of layout in your screenshot. You can code up template parts for each "Layout" and then the user can construct a page with any of the layouts you have configured in any order they want.